# Swift rendering static cells with dynamic content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a **static** `UITableView` with *n* columns and 1 section. The cells are detailed with some **dynamic** content passed from another `UIViewController`. 
My solution is the following: I make a call in `viewDidAppear` to present the dynamic content and eventually reload the view:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setupDetails()
    }

fileprivate func setupDetails() {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: [0,0] as IndexPath)?.detailTextLabel?.text = "..."
        tableView.cellForRow(at: [0,1] as IndexPath)?.detailTextLabel?.text = "..."
        // .... multiple cells

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

The thing I don't like is that the content is updated after the view is shown to the user (thanks to the `viewDidAppear` call). 
For what concerns working on the `cellForRow()` method, I could not have it working given the fact that the cell is statically created in my Storyboard. 
My question is if there exists a pattern to be used in this specific case which I didn't think of. I basically want the view to be loaded before the view is presented, as if I was working with dynamic cells.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if there exists a pattern to be used in this specific case

Yes. Don't use a static table. Your table is *not* static! "Static" means "never changes". Your table is the opposite of static; it *does* change. It is dynamic!

So, use an ordinary dynamic table. Maintain a data model that is consulted by the Three Big Questions (the data source methods). To update the table with new data, first update the data model, and then call `reloadData`. That will cause `cellForRowAt` to *be called* for you, and you'll populate each cell from the data model. That is *much* more efficient than what you're doing.

As for the flash, that's just a matter of timing; use `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I meant static I intended that the number of cells does not change, what's changing instead is the cell `detail label`. The reason why I am not using a dynamic `tableView` is that I wish to customize the cell differently in my Storyboard (given the fact the numbers of cells to display does not change), e.g. `sliders`, `textfield` etc. The problem with the `viewWillAppear` is that with my current implementation the `cellForRow()` returns nil at that time, so I cannot do my updates. Do you suggest to create a static structure as data source for the dynamic table?

Comment: Despite what you say, what you're describing is a dynamic table view. It sounds like you're just being lazy (not meant to be insulting; we are all lazy, it's a virtue!). Bite the bullet and do this properly. Use a normal UITableView with a data source and delegate and do all the work of configuration in the data source and delegate methods. If you have elaborate cell types, use UITableViewCell subclasses and design them, if you like, in the storyboard as different prototypes, or use _.xib_ files.

Comment: No insult taken:) I just not completely agree with what you say, I associated the dynamicity of the UITableView to the unknown _number_ of rows presented, not purely on the content! In my mind the static table by definition is the one in the Settings app (iOS) with predefined number of rows, but if you switch on/off the Wifi/Bluetooth you get a feedback in the related cell `detailLabel`, which displays the current status. This is basically the same use case I have, the core cell is the same, the changing component is the status (ie `detailLabel`). Tell me if I'm mistaken

Comment: Obviously I'm saying you _are_ mistaken. Changing the content of a static table is completely contrary to the point of the static table.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ViewDidAppear if you don't want you change to show to the user.  Use ViewWillAppear and the view will already be in its final state when the user first sees it.

Comment: With my current implementation this does not work, in fact upon `viewWillAppear` the tableView is not loaded yet, therefore my `tableView.cellForRow()` returns nil. That's the main reason for my question :)

Comment: Don't use the tableView to access your fields.  Ctrl+drag outlets to your fields directly into the UITableViewController if this is a static tableView